# verificar si una lista en un map esta vacia en flutter / dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Buenas soy nuevo en esto de flutter/dart y estoy teniendo un mal rato con cosas simples.

tengo este codigo: `var  a = {'uno':1,'dos':[{'tres':3}]};`

Lo que necesito es verificar si esta vacio la lista en la propiedad 'dos'.

He probado de esta forma `a.forEach((key, value) => key == 'ITEMS' && value == [] ? print('esta vacio') : print('esta lleno'));`, el resultado es:
`esta lleno esta lleno`

Y esta forma tambien `a.containsKey('dos');` y esto me devuelve true.

Tambien he tratado de esta forma `a['ITEMS'] == [] ? print('esta vacio') : print('esta lleno');`, pero el resultado es erroneo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es sencillo, solo necesitas obtener primero el array `dos` y luego solo validas:

```dart
  var a = {
    'uno': 1,
    'dos': [
      {'tres': 3}
    ]
  };
  final isEmpty = (a['dos'] as List).isEmpty;
  print(isEmpty);

//result = false
```

o

```dart
  var a = {
    'uno': 1,
    'dos': []
  };
  final isEmpty = (a['dos'] as List).isEmpty;
  print(isEmpty);

//result = true
```

Comment: Dios mio... que respuesta tan elegante >.<, habia realizado algo asi a.values.toList() y desde ahi hacer algo, pero tu respuesta es ufff, muchas gracias. Podrias indicame algun curso o libro para aprender dart/flutter??

Comment: Nada mejor que empezar por la documentación : https://flutter.dev/docs ,  en youtube también hay varios tutoriales de dart/flutter, y si quieres algo más avanzado de flutter, te recomiendo mi canal de youtube :)  youtube.com/diegoveloper :D